# Is node js v17.4.0 the stable version to create docker image which I can use for long time?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, docker, dockerfile

I want to create the docker image for my angular app but I am confused, which latest version of nodejs should I use which should be stable and long time support ?

I am thinking of  using **v17.4.0**

```
FROM node:12.16.1
ENV ARG ""
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/
WORKDIR /usr/src/
COPY . /usr/src/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/ says 16.13.2 is the current LTS

Answer (score 1):

No,

According to https://nodejs.org/en/download/:

```
Latest LTS Version: 16.13.2 (includes npm 8.1.2)
```

Any versions other than LTS are not recommended for stable and long time use.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly numbered Node.js versions are supported until the next evenly numbered version is released. In other words, only evenly numbered versions get LTS (long term support) treatment. You shouldn't base your container image on any 17.x version, but use the latest 16.x version.